# how to mock hard coded objects using powermock. The PowerMockito.whenNew(<someClass>.class).thenreturn(<something>) is not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock

i'm trying to test a class CallingClass.java. This class creates a new instance of a class AddClass.java and using this instance it calls a function 'add' which is present inside AddClass.java. i want to mock the behaviour of this function 'add', i used powermock,i mocked the creation of instance variable but still this mock is not being used.

here is the code

AddClass.java

```
package com.samples;

public class AddClass {

    public int add(int a,int b)
    {
        int c;
        c=a+b;
        return c;
    }

}
```

CallingClass.java

```
package com.samples;

public class CallingClass {

    public int Calling_function(int a,int b)
    {
        int x;
        AddClass adding=new AddClass();
        x=adding.add(a, b);
        return x;
    }

}
```

CallingClassTest.java  //this is the test class

```
package com.samples;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;



public class CallingClassTest {

    @Test
    public void testCalling_function() {
        int actual;
        int a=5;
        int b=4;
        AddClass aobj=Mockito.mock(AddClass.class);
        PowerMockito.when(aobj.add(a, b)).thenreturn(10);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(AddClass.class).thenreturn(aobj);
        CallingClass c=new CallingClass();
        actual=c.Calling_function(a, b);
        assertEquals(10,actual);

        }

}
```

can someone tell me how should i mock the behaviour of the function 'add' present inside AddClass.java

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: Did you read the [funny manual](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage)? *At first sight* I would say some runner and @PrepareForTest are missing

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public class CallingClass {
   private AddClass addClass;

   public CallingClass(){
     this.addClass = addClass;
   }

   public int Calling_function(int a,int b){
     //int x;
     //x=addClass.add(a, b);
     //return x;
     //inline above three lines
     return addClass.add(a,b);
   }
}
```

And in your test class you can simply do,

```
public class CallingClassTest {
  private CallingClass callingClass;
  private AddClass addClass;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
   addClass = Mockito.mock(AddClass.class);
   callingClass = new CallingClass(addClass);
 }

  @Test
  public void testCalling_function() {
     int actual;
     int a=5;
     int b=4;
     Mockito.when(addClass.add(a, b)).thenreturn(10);
     actual=callingClass.Calling_function(a, b);
     assertEquals(10,actual);
    }
}
```

You should consider renaming variables and methods:

- Descriptive variable names
- Method names should start with a verb and first letter should be lower case

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some annotations over your test class.

Try the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CallingClass.class, AddClass.class})
public class CallingClassTest {
    ...
```

With these annotations in place, I think your unit tests should run fine.